# Qt Creator displaying stale or wrong errors

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator 4.10.2 as IDE on a Fedora Workstation installation, trying to get through excercises in "C++ Crash Course". One of the excercises requires you to declare a concept and apply it to a function. Here's my code:

```
template<typename T> concept Integer = std::is_integral<T>::value;

template<Integer T> T mode (const T* values, size_t length) {...}
```

Initially, the build environment wasn't configured for C++20 or using concepts, so I added the following to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fconcepts")
```

Not sure if this is the right way, just something I googled up (possibly on this very site). Now, the project is building and running as it should... but the editor shows an avalanche of errors and warnings ("unknown type name Integer" etc.). "Tools->C++->Inspect C++ Code Model" shows `-fconcepts` and `-std=c++2a`, so supposedly it picked up my settings correctly.

This issue does not stop me from continuing with the examples but it's very uncomfortable working with dozens of errors always on. I believe I misconfigured the IDE somewhere, but how exactly? Thank you for your time.

Comment: _but the editor shows an avalanche of errors and warnings_ The editor (syntax highlighting, inline checking) may not yet be prepared for C++20. I have some similar experiences in VS2013 with C++11. Some of the constructs appear suspicious for the compiler beside of that they compile and run fine. I'm afraid you have to be patient until Qt Creator has been updated for the new standard. C++20 is very new, isn't it?

Comment: @Scheff, that's too bad. I thought it was simply running some gcc/clang utility and displaying the results. Besides, shound't it also complain about concepts themselves? Oh well.

Comment: Not sure what Qt creator uses for syntax highlighting but I found it in the Qt doc.: [Semantic Highlighting](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-highlighting.html). It claims to use [KSyntaxHighlighting](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/syntax-highlighting/html/index.html) and you may research about it what it's capable.

Comment: _Besides, shound't it also complain about concepts themselves?_ Not sure. Syntax highlighting doesn't do a ful compile (AFAIK). Concerning inline error checking I'm not sure. However, the compiler is the authoritative instance. If inline error checking reports something which does compile fine then the error checking isn't done with compiler (which might be too much effort - too slow) and it's just wrong. That's what I'm used to over the years. But the tools became significantly better over the years. So, you shouldn't give up your hope... ;-)